# xhttp POST xml data to server

Tags: javascript, php

I am using WordPress. My knowledge of php and javascript is ok. I dont know jQuery, so would be happy is the answers are with a javascrip/php solution.

My javascript creates an XML DOM document (from a Google maps path it creates the trk, trkseg and trkpt nodes of a gpx file). I then pass this data to the server using XHTTP and POST where a php script should receive the data and then do something with it before finally storing it to the server.

But I am stuck. I have tried POSTing the data in 2 ways - 'Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and also also 'application/xml'.

To be honest I am not sure if the problem is on the client or server side.

I would be very grateful if anyone can spot what is wrong. I have attached the relevant code. Some explanations to your answers would be great so I can learn... I have looked and looked on the Internet...

From client:

```
function sendDataToServer(line) {
var updatedTrackDOM = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
var trk = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("trk");
var name = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("name");
trk.appendChild(name);
var trkseg = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("trkseg");

var pathArr = line.getPath();
for (var i = 0; i < pathArr.length; i++){
    var trkpt = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("trkpt");
    trkpt.setAttribute("lat", pathArr.getAt(i).lat());
    trkpt.setAttribute("lon", pathArr.getAt(i).lng());
    var ele = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("ele");
    ele.innerHTML = 100;
    trkpt.appendChild(ele);
    var time = updatedTrackDOM.createElement("time");
    time.innerHTML = '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z';
    trkpt.appendChild(time);
    trkseg.appendChild(trkpt);
};
trk.appendChild(trkseg);
updatedTrackDOM.appendChild(trk);


var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var text = 'Response received: ' + this.responseText;
        alert(text);
    }
};
xhttp.open("POST", 'script_update_track.php', true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send("Path=" + updatedTrackDOM);
}
```

And from server the (script_update_track.php content):

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);
include($path.'wp-load.php');

$newFile = $_POST['Path'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file($newFile) or die ("Error: Cannot create object2");
$startlat = $xml->trk[0]->trkseg[0]->trkpt['lat'];

echo 'Check it worked by posting this: ', $startlat;
?>
```

Comment: A quick test would be to display what the PHP script is being sent.  `print_r($_POST);` would be a start and add this output to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using $var = print_r($_POST, true); and returning this to the client (in the Alert box) I see Array ([newFile]=>[object XMLDocument].  Would be great if this helps you to give me a tip!

Comment: Not sure about Javascript, but I think when you send `updatedTrackDOM`, this is the object, you need to export `updatedTrackDOM` as XML before passing it on.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this. I guess I need to use var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( gpxDocTemplate ); (I am a novice, so baby steps for me...!)

Comment: In the end I did not know its seems not to be possible to POST a DOM object. Now I simply send all lat / long as one long string. Simple, but it works. Thanks for the response.